# Debug obfuscated by .NET Reactor release with pdb files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, obfuscation, pdb-files, net-reactor

I compile **ASPNET Core 2.2** application, obtain **pdb** files and then run **.NET Reactor** obfuscation on assemblies. I have all components: binary, source code, pdb files.

Before .NET Reactor run I'm able to create **dump file** and debug it using .pdb in Visual Studio 2017.
But after .NET Reactor run I get following symbol status in all included dll:
**"Binary was not built with debug information."**

More over, .NET Reactor does not change pdb at all. it just copies them to new destination.

How can I debug obfuscated application in this case?

Comment: You don't, or at least, you do so without symbols. The best .NET Reactor has to offer is a [stack trace deobfuscator](https://www.eziriz.com/help/source/deobfuscator.html), if you've built a mapping file. This will allow you to tell where the problem occurred; to debug it effectively you'd need to replay the issue on a non-obfuscated instance. This would be true even if .NET Reactor provided full debugging symbols, since you'd be debugging the obfuscated binary -- as that *by design* contains all sorts of rewrites to make debugging *harder*, symbols are just the start of the problem.

Comment: As I correctly understand .NET Reactor does not have such feature, but some other obfuscators like Crypto Obfuscator, Eazfuscator.NET have? Obfuscator should generate new pdb files to fit obfuscated dll.

Comment: Yes, obfuscators can generate new symbol files to match the new assemblies, but this will still only be of limited value, if the obfuscator is doing its job right. It is not possible to generate a symbol file that somehow undoes all the things the obfuscator did to the code that make it comprehensible again -- for example, stepping through the code can go all over the place and enter methods that don't even exist in the original because the control flow was altered. If all the obfuscator does is rename symbols, though, there's no problem generating new debug symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 kinds of `pdb` specifications. There is only a problem with the newer portable `pdb`  specification (it causes internally an exception and `.NET Reactor` only copies the file) .

And `.NET Reactor` doesn't support it yet.
Make sure to build dll using `"full"` debugging information:
[image]

It should resolve the issue. As for my case, some why my `VisualStudio` ignores this option and keeps using `'portable'` even if option is full. It can be seen as it starts from `BSJB`:

[image]

Currently `.NET Reactor` team is aware about the issue and promise to add support in in the next major release.
Till that tine try to use `'full'` debugging information in settings.

Answer (score 1):

The latest .NET Reactor version is able to handle both pdb specifications (classic pdb, portable pdb) now.